# Systematic review: Inclusion paper

Tags: phd, research-process

I am doing a systematic review of the medical field. I am looking for the current definition of exacerbation in CF patients used in the literature.
my question is..
Should we include a book in the data extraction process of the systematic review? 
Or just include the primary research articles?

Comment: The content of your research is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Like many answers on this site, that depends on a lot of factors. For instance, you might need to determine whether the book contains original research that was not published elsewhere. Most often, material contained in books has originally appeared elsewhere in other forms (as technical reports, research articles, etc). However, in some fields some books are occasionally on the cutting edge of research and might contain truly original material; this is true in technical fields like engineering.

Answer (score 0):

An important part of a review paper is introducing the reader to the topic you're reviewing. Even books that are not at the cutting edge of the current research can be extremely helpful as introductory texts in case the reader wants to learn more. From this perspective, it may make sense to cite them.